# When playing DVDs with VLC media player, both video and audio pause several times per second

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, dvd

When using the [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to play DVDs both video and 
audio pause several times per second. This makes VLC 
unusable for playing DVDs.

Windows Media Player works without any problems.

Is there a solution for this problem?

This problem appears for all the versions of VLC I have tried, including the newly realeased v1.0.0.

Platform: Windows XP 64 bit, 8 GB RAM, AMD Quad core 
(Phenom), built-in sound (ASUS motherboard, Realtek).

**Update 1**: the problem is solved by selecting "Higher
latency" for
menu Tools/Preferences/Input & Codecs/Default Caching level.
See Keck's answer for further details.

Comment: Have they added shuffle yet to VLC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adjusting a few settings.

In the video tab of your settings, ensure that the following are checked

- Skip Frames
- Accelerated video output
- Use hardware YUV->RGB conversions.

Also, go to the "Inputs & Codecs" section and adjust the Caching level to one with higher latency.

If you still have problems, naturally head over to the VideoLAN forums and see what else they recommend.

Comment: The first 3 were already checked. Setting the Caching level actually solved the problem! Thanks! (Although there seems to be a bug so Custom is always selected when the preferences dialog is reopened).