# How can I stop a video file to stop sputtering while I watch it?

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, visual-artifacts

I was finding that when watching some video files using VLC 2.0.6 (Twoflower) that I have on my hard drive, they were sputtering quite a bit (stopping and starting causing video and audio artifacts and dropouts).  This is especially noticeable when I increase the playback rate above 1.0x.

These video files are small (around 300-700MB+) and my computer isn't that old (about 6 months).  Its a Dell Inspiron N411Z computer with an Intel Core i5-2450M 2.5GHz, 6.00GB of RAM, 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 OS with a rating of 4.8 (which is the graphics performance).  The hard drive is a 500GB SATA drive with 8MB cache and 3GB transfer spinning at 5400RPM ([complete specs can be found here](http://www.ebay.ca/ctg/Toshiba-MK5076GSX-500-GB-Internal-5400-RPM-2-5-HDD2J93-Hard-Drive-/108236831#prodDescr)).

Codec of one of the videos as reported by ffmpeg:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 608x336 [SAR 1:1 DAR 38:21], 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

This is quite annoying, and I don't think it should be happening.  I did see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/227528/how-to-fix-choppy-video-with-vlc-player), but I don't think it's quite the same issue as that one only refers to video and not audio.

How many others have had this occur and what has your fix been?

Comment: What kind of codec (avc1, x264, xvid etc) and container (mkv, mp4, divx, ..)?

Comment: @Bora: updated question

Comment: Still, have you tried turning GPU acceleration off?

Comment: @Bora: I couldn't find any GPU options in VLC 2.0.6.  However, why would this matter?  Wouldn't turning off GPU acceleration make it slower?  Also, since caching the video, it makes it faster, so I don't think it's a GPU thing.

Comment: There is an update to 2.0.7. Did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I dled it and it still has video/audio dropouts without using the caching fix I suggested.

Comment: Related: *[When playing DVDs with VLC media player, both video and audio pause several times per second](http://superuser.com/questions/11135)*

Comment: This is quite old, but I'd like to report that it turns out, my HD wasn't working correctly. I copied the drive to another using clonezilla and was amazed how fast my computer became.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be a disk access issue.  By putting the movie into the cache, this problem goes away.  The issue is how to put it in the OS's disk cache in the first place.  I've written this simple batch script:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\cp.exe "%~1" /dev/null
```

That of course requires that [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) is loaded on to the system.  MinGW didn't work as it caused this error:

```
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file `/dev/null': Invalid request code
```

Seems like `cp` isn't implemented correctly under [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).  I did try this:

```
copy /b %1 nul
```

But for some reason, it didn't seem to work *as* well (though it did work better than not doing it at all).

### Implementation

I named the script **`cacheFile.bat`** and put the script into a folder (like *%USERPROFILE%\bin*, which I created) and then created a `.lnk` to that file in the `SendTo` folder to that file which I named **`cache file`** (to get to the `SendTo` folder easily, type `shell:SendTo` and hit enter at the *Start->Run* prompt or on the *Explorer* address bar).  By setting the `Run` properties of the `.lnk` file to `Minimized`, the window doesn't show up, except in the task bar.  This is done by right clicking on the `.lnk` file, selecting `Properties` and in the `Shortcut` tab, set `Run` to `Minimized`.

Now I can right click on a movie and put it into the cache.

[image: context menu]

The batch file can be of course modified to cache it and then run VLC immediately after doing so, but this way I don't have to wait for the file to be fully copied before starting to view the video, or while watching the video, I can cache it again if required.

Comment: 6 month old PC with disk access that bad? Which one is it? Are you sure the disk's not failing?

Comment: I'm running at 1.5-2.0x playback with disk access at about 15-40MBps and CPU usage at 20%-30% while showing the video and 15-20% while not.  The disk is apparently at 7% fragmentation and has about 8GB of 466GB left.  I'm going to do a defrag and a disk check and see if that improves things, but doing this is a lot smoother then some other times when I've heard audio artifacts causing intermittent crackling, chirping and squelching even when the video wasn't a problem after having this computer for a month or so.  Oh and I've already stated what type of computer it is.

Comment: By "Which one is it?" I was actually referring to your HDD, what sort of RPM it has, cache etc.

Comment: According to Device Manager, its a Toshiba MK5076GSX which is 5400 RPM with an 8MB cache, capable of 3GB/s transfer ([see here for complete specs](http://www.ebay.ca/ctg/Toshiba-MK5076GSX-500-GB-Internal-5400-RPM-2-5-HDD2J93-Hard-Drive-/108236831#prodDescr)).  So it's a little on the slow side, but I think it should still be good enough for this.

Comment: This is quite old, but I'd like to report that it turns out, my HD wasn't working correctly. I copied the drive to another using clonezilla and was amazed how fast my computer became.